# How to capitalize one instance of a variable in a live template?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, webstorm, velocity, live-templates

I am trying to make a template for React useState:

```
const [item, setItem] = useState('value')

const [$state$, set$state$] = useState($init$);$end$
```

Since `item` is the same, only with a capital I, is it possible to auto-capitalize the first letter?

I am doing it in VS Code like this:

```
const [$1, set${1/(.*)/${1:/capitalize}/}] = useState($2)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly? Are you trying to do a "find and replace"?

Comment: when I am typing `state` I want the same text to appear in both places, only the second instance to start with a capital letter: `[item, setItem]`

Comment: "when I am typing `state`" - where? Is this a question about React or about code editing/writing?

Comment: @D.Pardal It's about IntelliJ live templates, independent of React, it's being used in React code but that's not really relevant, OP want a live template variable to be output in two different ways

Comment: This was the exact use case that I was trying to find the answer for. Thanks for asking this!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Create a second variable whose value depends on the first one.

For example, `$state_` has its value initialized to `capitalize(state)` in the edit variables dialog

```
const [item, setItem] = useState('value')

const [$state$, set$state_$] = useState($init$);$end$
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for commenting an old post, can you please update this answer with the most recent solution? The "Edit Variables" window is totally different now and I can't really understand how to make it work.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm using IDEA 2022 and the window looks pretty much the same. Please explain which part you're not understanding. A new question linking to this with your own screenshots would be the best, feel free to link it here so I can see it.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness and the fast answer, I created a new question as your requested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73611330/how-to-capitalize-a-variable-in-a-rider-live-template