# How to capitalize a variable in a Rider Live Template?

Tags: c++, rider, live-templates

I'm trying to follow [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61465362/how-to-capitalize-one-instance-of-a-variable-in-a-live-template/61465849?noredirect=1#comment129987648_61465849) to solve the issue but I can't understand if the problem is Rider itself (that differs from IDEA) or something that I am mistaking.

If I click on "Live Templates" I only have a list of languages and the interface is totally different from the Mac screenshot.

Opening the C++ section I can select the template that I want to edit and there's a section called "Edit variables" that I know and use, but there's no "Expression" field or table to fill.

In this case I need to make the "Current Solution Name" variable capitalized.

Thank you in advance for the help!

[image: Rider 2022 Screenshot]

Comment: It looks like you're supposed to edit the template right underneath its definition. For example, the `USTRUCT` live template has its code right below it. Do the sections expand when you select the template name. As you type a new variable name into that section, for example, `$myvar$`, I believe the `Edit Variables` button will be enabled.

Comment: I found a windows similar to yours clicking on "Other languages", Unfortunately I couldn't figure how to make these variables work with the C++ live templates, and I didn't find how to read the solution name from there too, I guess that Rider really differs from Idea then, I'll try to contact the JetBrains support too. Thank you for the tips